# PhoneGap NFC Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, nfc, phonegap-plugins

I have managed to run the phonegap nfc plugin on an Android 2.3 phone, however, when I run the app and scan tags I get Tag Type: undefined, max Size: undefined....can't seem to read the tag details including the tags unique ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same issue as [phonegap-nfc/issues/53](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/53).

The plugin developer, in email, said he will try to fix it.